# Correct wooden batten size to support heavy item on drywall

Tags: drywall, wood, studs, hanging, storage

I'm going to install the Ikea Boaxel wardrobe storage system and because I have plasterboard walls I going to screw horizontal battens into the wall studs and then attach the 2m Boaxel vertical rails to them.

However I need some guidance on what size timber to use for the horizontal battens. The Boaxel system has clothes rails and some shelves so will have a lot of weight.

I have some 18mm x 44mm planed timber. Is that sufficient or do I need larger timber? I plan to use 6mm x 80mm screws to attach the battens to the stud.

Also does it matter what length of screw I use to attach the Boaxel rails to the battens once they're in place? The largest diameter the rails will take is 4mm. If they're too short will the weight pull them out of the batten?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Why not screw them into the studs? You could still use Battens to even things out but your studs are what should be carrying the load. If you won’t be able to use the studs for direct support the thickness of the support will be dictated by the weight and how far away from the wall the unit hangs.

Comment: @EdBeal unfortunately the uprights that the rails and shelves are attached to have to be a certain distance apart meaning they won't be in the same place as the studs. That's why I'm thinking of attaching the battens to the studs and then the upright rails to the battens. The shelves and rails come out a distance of 40cm from the wall.